# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Python program

Tags: python

This is a simple python program for calculating area of triangle which is not working for all test cases. I've doubt that the first `try:` block of the program is creating the problem but I'm not sure about this. May be the value for ch is not getting specified so this may create more problems.

## The complete code is :-

```
# area of traingle
import cmath
import sys

def areaOfTriangle(z):
    flag = 0
    a, b, c, angle, area = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    print(" What information about the tiangle you have? ")
    print(" 1. Height and Base : ")
    print(" 2. Length of three sides of triange : ")
    print(" 3. Length of two sides and angle between them : ")
    print(" 4. EXIT : \n")
    try:
        if flag == 0 and z == 2:
            ch = int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    except:
        print("OOPS..!! something went wrong, try again")
        areaOfTriangle(2)
    if ch == 1:
        try:
            a = float(input(" Enter height and base : "))
            b = float(input())
        except:
            print("OOPS..!! something went wrong, try again")
            flag = 1
            areaOfTriangle(1)
        area = (a*b)/2
    elif ch == 2:
        try:
            a = float(input(" Enter length of three sides : "))
            b = float(input())
            c = float(input())
        except:
            print("OOPS..!! Something went wrong, try again")
            flag = 1
            areaOfTriangle(1)
        s = (a+b+c)/2
        area = cmath.sqrt((s) * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c))
        area = abs(area)
    elif ch == 3:
        try:
            a = float(input("Enter the base length : "))
            b = float(input("Enter the side length : "))
            angle = float(input("Enter the angle between the two sides : "))
        except:
            print("OOPS..!! Something went wrong, try again")
            flag = 1
            areaOfTriangle(1)
        area = (1/2) * a * b * cmath.sin(angle)
        area = abs(area)
    elif ch == 4:
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("wrong choice")
    print("The area of the triangle is ", area)
    return
areaOfTriangle(2)
```

NOTE : I'm passing `z` in the function `areaOfTriangle(Z)` only because I don't want the user to enter the choice again and again if any exception occurs after entering the choice once.

The Error which testing for different case is : -

```
amitwebhero@AmitKali:~$ python3.5 ~/python/basic\ programs/2-area-triange.py 
 What information about the tiangle you have? 
 1. Height and Base : 
 2. Length of three sides of triange : 
 3. Length of two sides and angle between them : 
 4. EXIT : 

Enter your choice : 1
 Enter height and base : 
OOPS..!! something went wrong, try again
 What information about the tiangle you have? 
 1. Height and Base : 
 2. Length of three sides of triange : 
 3. Length of two sides and angle between them : 
 4. EXIT : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amitwebhero/python/basic programs/2-area-triange.py", line 22, in areaOfTriangle
    a = float(input(" Enter height and base : "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amitwebhero/python/basic programs/2-area-triange.py", line 58, in <module>
    areaOfTriangle(2)
  File "/home/amitwebhero/python/basic programs/2-area-triange.py", line 27, in areaOfTriangle
    areaOfTriangle(1)
  File "/home/amitwebhero/python/basic programs/2-area-triange.py", line 20, in areaOfTriangle
    if ch == 1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ch' referenced before assignment
```

Here on this line `Enter height and base :` I pressed Enter key which created this error.

Comment: your assignment of `ch` is in an if block which means that if `flag == 0 and z == 2:` returns false, `ch` is never actually assigned

Comment: This is assigned for the first time when i call the function by passing 2 as the argument and for the rest of the time I don't want to change the value of ch so I'm keeping z as 1

Comment: You recursively called your function. Each call on the stack has its own set of local variables. There is no "first time" because you do not have a loop that would execute anything more than once.

Comment: it unfortunately doesnt work that way: since you are calling your function recursively, `ch` in your recursive call is not the same reference as `ch` in your original call

Comment: @dsh, R Nar.... I got it... this is something different in python right? I'm new to python and most of the time I've problem regarding the memory allocation of the variables. How to do a case study of the memory management of variables in pythons?

Comment: I suggest replacing your recursion with loops. Use loops to repeat the prompt for input when the input is invalid.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay No, recursion works this way in other languages too (Java, C, C++, Javascript, etc.)  It is the *scope* that you need to learn, not the memory management.

Comment: @dsh thank's..  but in c++ implementation of the same logic works perfectly

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay In C++ did you declare the local variables as `static`?  Or are they not locals but members of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final error is the solution to your problem :-

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ch' referenced before assignment`

It means variable ch is not assigned to any value and it is being accessed which creates the problem.

In line `27 of the code`, your are calling `areaOfTriangle(1)` and this recursion assigns the value of `z = 1` and this does not let your ch to be assigned because your if condition returns False.

You are thinking that the value of ch assigned in first call will remain same in the other recursion also but this does not happen exactly the way you thought.